# HTML Microdata for multiple organization telephone numbers

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I know how to markup a single telephone number for a local business.

But I'm unsure for a business with multiple phone numbers.

Do I need to bound each element with a new itemscope?

Example:

```
Company X
main tel: 555-1234
sale tel: 555-1235
help tel: 555-1236
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a new itemscope - you can just repeat the telephone property of the LocalBusiness:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Company X</h1>
  <!-- some other information here -->
  <p>
    main tel: <span itemprop="telephone">555-1234</span><br>
    sale tel: <span itemprop="telephone">555-1235</span><br>
    help tel: <span itemprop="telephone">555-1236</span>
  </p>
  <!-- some other information here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the semantics would still work with definition lists?

Comment: Yes, you could put the telephone numbers in a definition list, an unordered list, a small table - the HTML elements don't affect the microdata.